# Question about Notation in a Regular Language

Tags: automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

I am a little confused about the following notation:
$L' = \{xy|x\in L \ , y\in L^R\}$. I think this expression is not equivalent with palindrome but I am not entirely sure. For example, I think the following is true: if $L=a^*b$, then $xy = a^5bba^3$is in L. Sorry if this a trivial question but I want to make sure I didn't misunderstand any thing.

Thanks ahead!

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Hi, sorry, I got a typo here. I meant  L′={xy|x∈L ,y∈LR}.

Comment: If $L=a^*b$ then $L'=a^*bba^*$.

Comment: I see, so L' is just the concatenation of L and $L^R$.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it seems to be saying.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Last question, assume that L is regular, is it true that $L'$ will always be regular? I think not because L' can still potentially be a palindrome. Correct? Thanks for you help!

Comment: $L'$ cannot be a palindrome, because $L'$ is a language, and only words are palindromes. While the language of all palindromes is not regular, $L'$ cannot only consist of palindromes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An element of $L'$ could potentially be a palindrome, but that does not rule out the possibility that $L'$ is regular.  Some elements of the language $(\mathtt{a}+\mathtt{b})^\ast$ are palindromes—in fact it contains all possible palindromes—but the language is still regular.

A theorem says that if language $X$ is regular, than $X^R$, containing all the words of $X$ written backwards, is also regular. (The proof is essentially, run the FA for $X$, but backwards.)  And you know that the concatenation of any two regular languages is regular, so if $X$ is regular, so is the language $XX^R$ consisting of all strings formed by taking an element of $X$ and concatenating it with an element of $X^R$.

$XX^R$ does contain many palindromes, just as $(\mathtt{a}+\mathtt{b})^\ast$  does, but it also contains many non-palindromes, so it is *not* the same as $\{xx^R \mid x\in X\}$, which in general is not regular.

Your $xy$ example is correct: if $L=\mathtt{a}^\ast\mathtt{b}$ then you can choose $x=\mathtt{a}^5\mathtt{b} \in L$ and $y = \mathtt{ba}^3\in L^R$ and then $xy = \mathtt{a}^5\mathtt{b}\mathtt{ba}^3\in LL^R$ even though it is not a palindrome.

Comment: Thank you! That's very clear.

Comment: @y123liu It's easy to write a clear explanation in reply to someone who already understands everything correctly. $\ddot\smile$